# PyDev (or Eclipse): jump to definition (?) when I select some text

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I am using Eclipse with PyDev, and sometimes (quite often actually) when I select some text, the editor randomly jumps to definition of what I have selected, or to the beginning of the file. This is not the behaviour I want, would you know how to fix it? I have checked PyDev and Python settings but could not find the answer.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Humm, there's something strange there... PyDev will only do that if you do a Ctrl+Click on some work (i.e.: hold ctrl and then click on a word) or when you press F3.

If you want you can change the F3 binding in the preferences (window > preferences > general keys).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately it is some "mouse only" shortcut, in addition to F3.